# The subring of a field extension contains the field, is a subfield of the field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I am trying to prove that if $Q$ is an algebraic extension of $F$
($F$ is a field), if $R$ is a subring of $Q$, and we have 
$F\subseteq R$, then $R$ is a subfield of $Q$.

My first approach was to show every element has an inverse. But there was no result.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Thanks. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

You just have to show that, for any $x\in Q$, the subring $F[x]\subset Q$ is a field.

Now observe that $F[x]$ is a *finite-dimensional* $F$-vector space, which is an integral domain.

Consider, for any $y\in F[x]$, $y\ne 0$, the multiplication-by-$y$ map on $F[x]$: this is an *injective* $F$-*linear map*. What can you conclude about this map?

Comment: It is surjective and for some "a" we have ay=1 . Is it true?

Comment: Exactly. Actually, there is a more general lemma: if $A\subset B$ are integral domains such that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, then $B$ is a field if and only if $A$ is.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\in R$ and $f(a)=0$ with non-trivial $f\in F[X]$, then $f(X)=c(Xg(X)-1)$ for some $g\in F[X]$ and $c\in F^\times$. Then $b:=g(a)\in R$ and $c(ba-1)=f(a)=0$, so $ba=1$.